# String have wrong format when convert string to double

Tags: c#

This is the xml-File:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<ssbpreise>
    <ggvs>25.15</ggvs>
    <einblaspauschale>40</einblaspauschale>
    <pelletspreis>2.9</pelletspreis>
    <heizoel>0.4865</heizoel>
    <mwstpellets>5</mwstpellets>
    <mwstheizoel>22</mwstheizoel>
    <testparameter>testtest</testparameter>
</ssbpreise>
```

In my Code I try to convert the string

```
double einzelpreispellets = 0,
                einzelpreisheizoel = 0,
                einblaspauschale = 0,
                ggvs = 0,
                mwstpellets = 0,
                mwstheizoel = 0;
        try
        {
            if (devmode) writetolog(@"XML lesen.");

            using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(localFileserverBaseUrl + @"parameter.xml"))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.IsStartElement())
                    {
                        //return only when you have START tag  
                        switch (reader.Name.ToString())
                        {
                            case "pelletspreis":
                                writetolog(string.Format("{0}: gepeichert: {1} - aus xml: {2}", reader.Name.ToString(), einzelpreispellets, reader.ReadString()));
                                einzelpreispellets = XmlConvert.ToDouble(reader.ReadString());
                                break;
                            case "heizoel":
                                writetolog(string.Format("{0}: gepeichert: {1} - aus xml: {2}", reader.Name.ToString(), einzelpreisheizoel, reader.ReadString()));
                                einzelpreisheizoel = XmlConvert.ToDouble(reader.ReadString());
                                break;
                            case "einblaspauschale":
                                writetolog(string.Format("{0}: gepeichert: {1} - aus xml: {2}", reader.Name.ToString(), einblaspauschale, reader.ReadString()));
                                einblaspauschale = XmlConvert.ToDouble(reader.ReadString()); <=== this is row 322
                                break;
                            case "ggvs":
                                writetolog(string.Format("{0}: gepeichert: {1} - aus xml: {2}", reader.Name.ToString(), ggvs, reader.ReadString()));
                                ggvs = XmlConvert.ToDouble(reader.ReadString());
                                break;
                            case "mwstpellets":
                                writetolog(string.Format("{0}: gepeichert: {1} - aus xml: {2}", reader.Name.ToString(), mwstpellets, reader.ReadString()));
                                mwstpellets = XmlConvert.ToDouble(reader.ReadString());
                                break;
                            case "mwstheizoel":
                                writetolog(string.Format("{0}: gepeichert: {1} - aus xml: {2}", reader.Name.ToString(), mwstheizoel, reader.ReadString()));
                                mwstheizoel = XmlConvert.ToDouble(reader.ReadString());
                                break;
                            default:
                                writetolog(string.Format("Parameter konnte nicht zugeordnet werden : {0} | Wert: {1}", reader.Name.ToString(), reader.ReadString()));
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            writetolog("Error: " + e);
            return;
        }
```

This is my created logfileoutput:

> > 12:07:09: einblaspauschale: from the variabledeclaration: 0 - from xml: 40

> > 12:07:09: Error: System.FormatException: The input string is in the wrong format
> > at System.Number.ParseDouble(String value, NumberStyles options, NumberFormatInfo numfmt)
> > at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToDouble(String s)
> > at Webshopfiletransfer.Webshopfiletransfer.createCSVFile() in Webshopfiletransfer.cs:Row 322.

I am confuse, the value from the xml is available and would printed on the correct tag but the convertion to double seems to be wrong.

Is maybe anybody able to give me a tip where my misunderstanding is?

Comment: `XmlConvert.ToDouble("40")` works fine in [.net-core](https://tio.run/##TYwxC8IwEEbn5lccwSEdLA5uxUlHBUFBQRxiPEogycFdWpDS3x7j5vj43vecrB0xljKKTwNcPpIx9uqfunsMvVIuWBE4Mw1sI8yqkWyzdzCRf8PJ@mQkc309nmB5kPanNHtKQgG7G/uMR5/QrHTVYAdzrdZ1Qs7dlQ40vgIavd3odtFtr5pFLaV8AQ) can you please debug the program and check what `reader.ReadString()` returns?

Comment: You ReadString() for logging once, and then ReadString() the next value for processing.

Comment: It returns the string 40

Comment: Should I better use  reader.Value.ToString()  instead of ReadString()?

Comment: Nevermind, `Read()` advances the reader, `ReadString()` does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two problems: The first is that `ReadString()` seams to return the content once but you try to read it twice. So just do `var str = reader.ReadString()` and use `str` to refer to the content.

But You could also your `ReadContentAsDouble` instead of converting it yourself.

The second problem is that the converions is in the wrong order.
You need to do

```cs
var str = reader.ReadString();
einblaspauschale = XmlConvert.ToDouble(str);
writetolog(string.Format("{0}: gepeichert: {1} - aus xml: {2}", reader.Name.ToString(), einblaspauschale, str));
```

so that the logging output can be

```
einblaspauschale: gepeichert: 40 - aus xml: 40
```